# Return Number Of Times An ID Is Repeated

Tags: mysql

so I have two tables:

orders

```
order_id | user_id
   1     |     1
   2     |     1
   3     |     1
   4     |     2
   5     |     2
```

users

```
user_id | name
   1    | John
   2    | Mike
```

I want to return the id, name of the client and how many orders he has placed. Something like this:

```
user_id | name | num_orders
    1   | John |   3
    2   | Mike |   2
```

I tried to do the following query but it only returns the first user's name and the total amount of orders. This is the query I have:

```
SELECT 
  users.user_id,
  users.name,
  COUNT(orders.order_id) AS num_orders

FROM users

LEFT JOIN orders
ON users.user_id = orders.user_id

ORDER BY users.user_id DESC
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a GROUP BY statement. If you add in at the end

```
GROUP BY users.user_id
```

it should rectify your issues.

For more help on SQL statements try http://www.dofactory.com/sql/tutorial

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I didn't think of this sooner.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a `GROUP BY` clause. *It is used with aggregate functions (COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG) to group the results by one or more columns*. Here is how it works.

```
SELECT 
  users.name,
  users.user_id,
  count(users.user_id) as total
FROM users
LEFT JOIN orders ON users.user_id = orders.user_id
GROUP BY users.user_id
ORDER BY users.user_id DESC
```

And the results:

```
username |user_id | total
John     |   3    | 3
Mary     |   2    | 5
Carl     |   1    | 1
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I didn't think of this sooner.